# make 2nd button on web page the default for enter key

Tags: asp.net

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1"
            runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

how do i make button2 the default action when the Enter key is pressed?

See image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lH97.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `defaultbutton` property can be specified at the Form level in the form tag as well as at panel level in the `<asp:panel>` definition tag. The form level setting is overridden when specified at the panel level, for those controls that are inside the panel.

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/985791.aspx/1

Comment: when i click in the textbox it returns to button1 : ( good try

Comment: what happens when you press enter though? It should submit the from with the event raised from button 2?